# Calling Scala constructor with multiple argument lists

Tags: scala, constructor, higher-order-functions

In Scala, I can create a method that takes more than one argument list:

```
def myMethod(value: Int)(fn: (Int) => Unit) {
  fn(value)
}
```

and call it like this:

```
myMethod(10) { value => println(value) }
```

How can I do the same thing with a class constructor? How do I call it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_22).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class MyClass(val value: Int)(val fn: Int => Unit)
defined class MyClass

scala> new MyClass(10)({value => println(value)})
res0: MyClass = MyClass@17577f9
```

Comment: Ahh! The extra parentheses. I tried it without them and the compiler parsed it as extending the class as an anonymous subclass.

Comment: Could be also without the inner braces "{}": new MyClass(10)(value => println(value))

Comment: Where can I find documentation on this?